# Oracle Audit Trigger Prompt User Question

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, triggers, audit

I have two tables **TEST_DEPT** and **TEST_DEPT$AUDIT** in Oracle 11g.
I have made an *insert* *update* *delete* **after trigger**. However, the last column in the *Audit* table is called **REASON**. The idea is after making the *update* for example, Oracle to prompt the user to fill in the **REASON** column.

This is what the **after trigger** looks like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER auditDEPTAR AFTER
INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON TEST_DEPT FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    test TEST_DEPT$audit%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    IF    inserting THEN test.change_type := 'INSERT';
    ELSIF updating  THEN test.change_type := 'UPDATE';
    ELSE                 test.change_type := 'DELETE';
    END IF;

    test.changed_by   := user;
    test.changed_time := sysdate;    

    CASE test.change_type
    WHEN 'INSERT' THEN
       test.DEPTNO := :new.DEPTNO;
       test.DNAME  := :new.DNAME;
       test.LOC    := :new.LOC;
    ELSE
       test.DEPTNO := :old.DEPTNO;
       test.DNAME  := :old.DNAME;
       test.LOC    := :old.LOC;
    END CASE;

    INSERT INTO TEST_DEPT$audit VALUES test;
END;
```

Can it be done or should I use function or something else for workaround?
Please, help!

Comment: Triggers are background processes. You'll need to write something in the application to capture user input.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I come up with that idea. I just wanted to be sure that there is no workarounds.